# Работа с лямбдой. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Пытаюсь реализовать паттерн Стратегия при помощи лямбд в функциональном стиле. Идея: есть классы FlyBehavior, DanceBehavior, в них определил лямбды, правильно или нет - не знаю (первый раз с работаю с ними), теперь эти лямбды мне вроде как нужно передать в конструктор DecoyDuck, который наследуется от Duck. Как мне это сделать и правильный ли у меня подход?

```kotlin
open class Duck {
    fun swim() = println("I'm swimming!")

    open fun display() {}
}

class DecoyDuck : Duck() {

    override fun display() = println("I'm a decoy duck!")
}

class FlyBehavior(
        val flyWithWings: () -> Unit = {println("I'm flying!")},
        private val flyNoWay: () -> Unit,
) {}

class DanceBehavior(
        private val minuetBehavior: () -> Unit = {println("I'm dancing minuet!")},
        private val waltzBehavior: () -> Unit = {println("I'm dancing waltz!")},
        private val noDanceBehavior: () -> Unit
) {}
```

По моему должно выглядеть как то так, определяем функцию fly в Duck(), и передаем туда конкретную лямбду, для конкретного класса, например для DecoyDuck. DecoyDuck наследует функцию fly уже с конкретной нужной лямбдой

```kotlin
open class Duck(
        flyBehavior: () -> Unit,
        danceBehavior: () -> Unit,
        quackBehavior: () -> Unit
) {
//    fun fly(flyBehavior: () -> Unit) {
//        flyBehavior.invoke()
//    }

    fun swim() = println("I'm swimming!")

    open fun display() {}
}

class DecoyDuck: Duck(flyBehavior.flyNoWay, danceBehavior.noDanceBehavior, quackBehavior.muteQuackBehavior) {

    override fun display() = println("I'm a decoy duck!")
}
```

но как это реализовать я до сих пор не догоняю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно сделать нечто подобное:

```kotlin
open class Duck(
    private val flyBehavior: () -> Unit, // для того, чтобы использовать 
    private val danceBehavior: () -> Unit, // параметр конструктора после 
    private val quackBehavior: () -> Unit // того, как объект уже 
) { // инициализирован, нужно проставить ключевое слово val или var
    fun fly() = flyBehavior()

    fun dance() = danceBehavior()

    fun quack() = quackBehavior()

    fun swim() = println("I'm swimming!")

    open fun display() {}
}

object FlyBehavior {
    val flyWithWings: () -> Unit = { println("I'm flying!") }
    val flyNoWay: () -> Unit = {}
}

object DanceBehavior {
    val minuetBehavior: () -> Unit = { println("I'm dancing minuet!") }
    val waltzBehavior: () -> Unit = { println("I'm dancing waltz!") }
    val noDanceBehavior: () -> Unit = {}
}

object QuackBehavior {
    val justQuack: () -> Unit = { println("Quack motherfucker!") }
    val muteQuackBehavior: () -> Unit = {}
}

class DecoyDuck : Duck(FlyBehavior.flyNoWay, DanceBehavior.noDanceBehavior, QuackBehavior.justQuack) {
    override fun display() = println("I'm a decoy duck!")
}
```

Пример использования:

```kotlin
DecoyDuck().apply {
    fly()
    dance()
    quack()
    swim()
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего нужно немного не так, по идее, лямбды нужно завязать на класс Duck, потому что от него будут наследоваться другие классы уток, резиновая, деревянная, красноголовая и тд. От нас лишь будет требоваться создать объект, например деревянная утка, и при создании этого объекта будут вызываться конкретные лямбды для этого класса.

Comment: Объясню: вызывая метод fly(), который имеет DecoyDuck (определенный в Duck), у нас по сути должна вызываться лямбда, которая определена в классе Duck, она же в свою очередь должна вызывать лямбду, которую мы передали в Duck, при создании DecoyDuck, надеюсь вы меня понимаете(

Comment: Кажется, Вам просто нужно прокидывать лямбду в самый базовый класс, так? Изменил код  к тому, как я сейчас понимаю Вашу задачу

Comment: @NickolayDudin Увидел новую версию вопроса, у Вас, кажется, все получилось?)

Comment: функция вызывается, но не вызывается нужная лямбда(

Comment: @NickolayDudin кажется, нашел источник Вашей проблемы, сейчас изменю ответ)))

Comment: Вы меня спасли! Спасибо за Вашу помощь!)